# Jinja doesn´t render Django view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, jinja2

I´m working on a Django application but jinja doesn´t render the view. I need to separate those templates because I want to include specific content.

When I open *data.html* and *data2.html* I can see the values "1" respectively "4". But when I open *test.html* I don´t see the values. And multiple {% extends %} don´t work.

How can I load data.html and data2.html into test.html with the rendered data?

**My views in Django:**

```
def data1(request):

    return render(request, 'user_backend/pages/data.html',{'a':1,
                                                  "b":2,
                                                  "c":3})

def data2(request):

    return render(request, 'user_backend/pages/data2.html',{'d':4,
                                                  "e":5,
                                                  "f":6})
def test_temp(request):
    return render(request,"user_backend/pages/test.html")
```

**My templates:**

*test.html*

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<h1>Data from data.html</h1>

{% include "user_backend/pages/data.html" %}

{% include "user_backend/pages/data2.html" %}
```

*data.html*

```
<p>Data = {{a}} </p>
```

*data2.html*

```
<p>Data2 = {{d}} </p>
```

Comment: You render `test.html` without parameters. If you include a template it will *not* call the corresponding view. So `a` and `d` are indeed missing.

Comment: This is also sensical, since *not* every view per se renders a template, and a template can be rendered by multiple views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include only includes your html files and it will not call the corresponding view and render it for you. You should pass the values of `a` and `d` to test.html and while including, it will render the value for you inplace of the variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help!